# Time complexity of LinkedList.subList(int, int)

Tags: java, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

If I have a linked list of objects and I want the sublist from index 2 to 5. Is this operation o(1)? All you would need to do is null the reference to prev on the node at index 2, and return the node at index 2, correct? Does this require copying the contents of the linked list into another one and returning that or just setting the head to be the node at index 2?

Comment: Do you mean `java.util.LinkedList`? If so, `subList` is a view onto the original list, and it would be `O(n)`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList-int-int-,

Comment: @AndyTurner how could it be O(n) if it's a simple view over the original list. It's O(1). All it does is create an object referencing the original list and storing the from and to indices.

Comment: @JBNizet because you've got to iterate to the start node, and the end node. No? I mean, I suppose you could just `.get(i + start)` internally when you call `.get(i)` on the sublist... but wouldn't that be really inefficient?

Comment: @JBNizet.: How do you get the `start` and `end` node?

Comment: @JBNizet I stand corrected: `LinkedList` uses `subList` from `AbstractList`, so it does literally what I described. I'm surprised, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this operation o(1)?

In general, getting a sublist of a linked list is O(k), not O(1)<sup>*</sup>.

However, for any specific index value, such as 2, 5, or 5000, any operation is O(1), because a specific index becomes a constant that gets factored out from Big-O notation.

<sup>*</sup> Construction of sublist may be optimized such that you pay construction costs on the first navigation of sublist, rather on construction. In other words, constructing a sublist without iterating it is O(1).

Comment: But OP is not asking about specific operation. The heading says something different.

Comment: @coderredoc Right, that's why I said "in general" and in this specific case. His title is disconnected from the description, though.

Comment: Excuse me sir but can you reconsider what you are saying once more? Do you seriously mean that get to the kth node of a linked list from it's head is a O(1) operation?

Comment: @n4fengn Getting node `k` is O(k), and I say it explicitly at the top. Getting node 5000 is O(5000), which is the same as O(1).

Answer (score 0):

It's `O(n)` if you consider the general case of the algorithm. Even if you do what you said finding the n-th and m-th element would take a complete traversal of the list.

It's wrong to consider that the finding the sublist from 2 to 5 would be `O(1)`. It is O(1) ofcourse but it needs constant amount of operations to do that but are you creating an algorithm for `sublist(2,5)`? If you do that then ofcoursse it is always `O(1)`.

A better example is sorting 100 numbers is of O(1) complexity so is sorting 10,000 numbers. But it is not what we are concerned about. We want to know the nature of the algorithm based on the inputs fed to that algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `sublist` method runs in O(1) time. See [the source code for the method.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/AbstractList.java#AbstractList.subList%28int%2Cint%29)

All that this code does is return a new instance of SubList that is initialized with the list that `sublist` is invoked upon. No iteration is happening here, so the operation runs in constant time.

Comment: It's modifiable. the javadoc says: non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa